# Mathematica 12.0 crashed when printing a graph

Tags: graphs-and-networks, bugs, crash

My Mathematica crashes when I simply print a graph to a PDF. For example, when I input this:

```
Graph[{0->1}]
```

and then print(using the right-click menu) its output to a PDF, the notebook crashes.

Most puzzling of all, when I input this:

```
Graph[{0->1}, PlotTheme->"IndexLabeled"]
```

the output can be normally printed.

Can anyone give me a clue?

Comment: Both codes exported successfully in Mathematica 12.2 on Windows 10 64-bit.

Comment: You haven't shown the `Export` command that you used.

Comment: `Export["/Users/roberthanlon/Downloads/graph.pdf", Graph[{0 -> 1}]]` exports successfully with `12.0.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (April 7, 2019)`

Comment: @Bob Hanlon The `Export` command works, thanks for reminding me. But I'm still confused why the right click menu as well as `Ctrl+P` don't work.

Comment: Can you clarify what your question is? If you want to report a bug (you _should_ report the crash), this is not the appropriate place. Contact Wolfram Support, and include full information about your setup (operating system, Mathematica version, steps to reproduce).